# Sobreescribir Ctrl+c, Ctrl+x. ¿Por qué cortar en keyPressed y copiar en KeyRealased?

Tags: java, keypressevent

Llevo un rato intentando sobreescribir los atajos de copiar y cortar en un JEditorPane. El caso es que el comportamiento por defecto de estos dos atajos al copiar/cortar, ademas de la palabra en cuestión me pegaba un salto de linea.
Ya he conseguido sobreescribirlos despues de un poco de "investigación", pero no entiendo por qué uno va en un método y otro en otro. No me gusta hacer cosas sin comprender el por qué de ello,  así que cualquier ayuda a su comprensión se agradece.

Mi sobreescritura ha quedado tal que asi:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.isControlDown()){
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 88) {
            StringSelection textoCortado = new StringSelection(panel.getSelectedText());
            cb.setContents(textoCortado, textoCortado);
            Main.getFondo().getPanelTexto().replaceSelection("");
    }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.isControlDown()){
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 67) {
            StringSelection textoCopiado = new StringSelection(panel.getSelectedText());
            cb.setContents(textoCopiado, textoCopiado);
        }
    }

}
```

Añadir que, si pregunto esto, es porque no me funciona si los coloco al reves, por ejemplo...

Comment: Se me hace muy raro que si simplemente intercambias el nombre de los dos métodos deje de funcionar. De hecho, para mí lo lógico sería poner todo el código en un mismo método.

Comment: A mi también. El caso es que si pongo el cortar en keyReleased, el texto "desaparece" pero al intentar pegar el cortapapeles está vacio (me da la sensación de que hace mi cortar, yluego el de windows, y como el texto ya esta "eliminado", o sea, no hay selección, no guarda nada en el portapapeles). Si en cambio pongo el copiar en el keyPressed, no me sobreescribe el funcionamiento de Ctrl+c sino que tira del de windows, copiandome los saltos de linea...